Relation of sigprocmask and pthread_sigmask for multithreaded program
sigprocmask(2) says:

Each of the threads in a process has its own signal mask.

, but also:

The use of sigprocmask() is unspecified in  a  multithreaded  process;  see pthread_sigmask(3).

pthread_sigmask(3) states, that:

The  pthread_sigmask()  function is just like sigprocmask(2), with the difference that its use in multithreaded programs is explicitly  specified  by POSIX.1.  Other differences are noted in this page.

, but than there are no notes about that.
However https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/816-5137/gen-19/index.html says, that:

The call to sigprocmask() in a multithreaded process is equivalent to a call to pthread_sigmask().

and calling sigprocmask also works.
So it is safe to call sigprocmask? Is it intended?

pthread_sigmask is a wrapper around the sigprocmask syscall. It is largely similar. But, it will prevent one from blocking signals used by pthreads to do its job (e.g. SIGCANCEL used by pthread_cancel). To be sure, download the source for glibc and look at the implementation of pthread_sigmask.

Sounds like it's safe if you're using Solaris. Other OSes? Consult their documentation.

I would say that that answers my question. Can someone write an answer with that, please?


So it is safe to call sigprocmask? Is it intended?

It is not portable for a multithreaded process to call sigprocmask(), in the sense that the POSIX standard says:

The sigprocmask() function shall be equivalent to pthread_sigmask(), except that its behavior is unspecified if called from a multi-threaded process, and on error it returns -1 and sets errno to the error number instead of returning the error number directly.

The bit about the return value is probably what the manual page you were looking at was talking about as "noted in this page".  That does not necessarily mean "presented in a Notes section".
If Solaris is the only execution environment you care about then its docs do seem to say that you can use sigprocmask() even in multithreaded programs (but don't overlook the difference in return value semantics).  On the other hand, if you want to provide for broad portability by relying only on POSIX, then you must not assume that it is safe for a multithreaded program to call sigprocmask().
On the third hand, in a POSIX environment, any program can call pthread_sigmask() and expect the documented behavior, even if it does not otherwise use pthreads. (Every process has at least one thread, that being the one that enters main()).

and calling sigprocmask also works.

It is extremely fraught to try to evaluate whether C code has well defined behavior by running it to see what happens.  Even if the observable behavior appears to be what you want, you cannot be confident that there isn't any other, unwanted behavior, or that you might not see different behavior under other circumstances.  Such experiments do not inspire confidence in me.
